# Creat a transparency mask such as clipping mask?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask, brush, clipping-mask

I can see a "`Creat mask`" button in the transparency pannel. Its such an easy way to quickly add texture on my shape. But the thing is that its made to manage transparency whereas i would like **creat texture with color.**
The best way to do it is to creat a clipping mask but its not as easy to do because i have to go to `object > clipping mask > creat`… I would rather have a button like the transparency pannel.

Is there any way to creat a **clipping mask** with in a pannel ( such as the transparency pannel ) or anyway to completly change color in the transparency mask instead of made the transparency change ?

Comment: Hit Ctrl+7? Or you could make a action in actions panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no panel for a clipping mask.

You can however use an **Opacity mask**, which is what the Transparency Panel creates, to create a masked color.

You just need to mask a colored object and stack objects.....

[image]

Comment: I think its the best way to do it